# Node.js in console adds spaces in template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, encoding, template-literals

I have simple JavaScript statments in file `simple.js`:

```
let t = `
`;

console.log(t.length);
```

Now in `t` the only char is `\n`. In Windows cmd I input:

```
node simple.js // -> 1
```

All rigth. But when I try:

```
node

.load simple.js // -> 769, t[0] is '\n', other 768 chars are spaces
```

I thing that something wrong with encoding, but what exactly and how to fix it?

Comment: I get 1 for both,  is `simple.js` exactly the lines of code you have shown?.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. In both cases, I get `1` as output. Have you checked the file's current encoding? Notepad++ can be really useful for such cases.

Comment: @Keith, yes, exactly this lines

Comment: @TasosK. file in utf-8, I work with it in VS Code